# GAE Datastore Composite Filter error

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

What actually is happening when I set the datastore filters like this?

```
Query("Product").setFilter(filter1).setFilter(filter2);
```

I found that the result is neither *AND* or *OR*.

I also tried to use `CompositeFilterOperator.and`, but I got `DatastoreNeedIndexException`, where it should return something that match the *AND* composite filter.

Comment: my filter1 is on string, and filter2 is on int

Comment: `DatastoreNeedIndexException` means that you are missing an index to perform your query. Add it to your *datastore-indexes.xml* and this should solve the error. Moreover, if I'm not wrong, your second `setFilter` will override the first, so you will be only searching for this second filter.

Comment: I thought all the entries in the datastore are automatically indexed? So i need to create the index that matches my query?

I think you are right. The 2nd filter will override 1st filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App engine predefined a simple index on each property of an entity. An app engine can define further custom indexes in an index configuration file named `datastore-indexes.xml`, which is generated in your application's `/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated` directory.

You can look at this blog:

http://rlabs.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/fixing-appengine-error-no-matching-index-found-this-query-needs-this-index/